# WebSocket connection does not happen and connection request gets 400 error NGINX+Daphne+Django+Channels on Ubuntu AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket, django-channels, daphne

I followed tutorial for deploying websockets for Django-channels using Daphne and Nginx.
Here is what my **NGINX.conf** at etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ looks like

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_server_ip;
    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 128M;

    location /static {
    # exact path to where your static files are located on server
    # [mostly you won't need this, as you will be using some storage service for same]
        location /static {
                 alias /mywebsite/static;
        }

    }

    location /media {
    # exact path to where your media files are located on server
    # [mostly you won't need this, as you will be using some storage service for same]
        alias /mywebsite/media;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/mywebsite/run/uwsgi.sock;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 300s;
    
    #path to proxy my WebSocket requests
    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:9001/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    access_log /mywebsite/log/dev-nginx-access.log;
    error_log /mywebsite/log/dev-nginx-error.log;
}
```

Now my **daphne.service** file looks like below

```
[Unit]
Description=Mywebsite Daphne Service for websockets
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/mywebsite/
#edit myproject
#If your daphne is not installed globally and is inside your #environment, enter the complete path to daphne
ExecStart=/mywebsite/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 9001 mywebsite.asgi:application
Restart=on-failure
#KillSignal=SIGQUIT
#Type=notify
#NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the **asgi.py** file looks like below

```
"""
ASGI config for mywebsite project.
It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import chatapp.routing

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mywebsite.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": get_asgi_application(),
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            dark.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

my **routing.py** file looks like below

```
# chatapp/routing.py
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

my JavaScript code for the above configuration is `ws://my_server_ip:9001/ws/chat/lobby/`

the entire setup works without NGINX I mean if I just do `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080` and have code for WebSocket in my JavaScript as `ws://my_server_ip:8080/ws/chat/lobby/` it works fine and smooth

apart from this the wsgi aspect of my webapp is running on uwsgi and running quite successfully

I have deployed it on Ubuntu 20.04 on AWS EC2 instance. I am getting the trouble connecting my WebSocket through NGINX.

when I check error logs it shows nothing and in the access.log it shows like

```
42.105.172.132 - - [19/Feb/2022:19:26:48 +0000] "GET /dark/inbox/notifications/api/unread_list/?max=10 HTTP/1.1" 200 38 "http://my_ip_address.com/dark/app-chat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Mobile Safari/537.36"
42.105.172.132 - - [19/Feb/2022:19:26:53 +0000] "GET /dark/inbox/notifications/api/unread_list/?max=10 HTTP/1.1" 200 38 "http://my_ip_address.com/dark/app-chat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Mobile Safari/537.36"
---------------focus on line below this is the access log giving 400 status---------------------
***42.105.172.132 - - [19/Feb/2022:19:27:00 +0000] "GET /ws/chat/lobby/ HTTP/1.1" 400 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Mobile Safari/537.36"***
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
42.105.172.132 - - [19/Feb/2022:19:27:01 +0000] "GET /dark/inbox/notifications/api/unread_list/?max=10 HTTP/1.1" 200 38 "http://my_ip_address.com/dark/app-chat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

I spend days on it to find a solution but could not able to find one. How do I solve this? I also checked the status of **all service files of daphne, nginx, uwsgi, redis all are working fine and enabled to get started by systemctl.**

***Is there any error in my daphne.service and/or nginx.conf?***
I would be grateful for whatever direction I could get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this answer so that It could be useful for everyone facing the issue I faced...The only point I needed to do was to open the 9001 port on ec2 management console that's it!! this solved the issue!
So you should open which ever post that u have in your `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 9001 mywebsite.asgi:application` after the **`-p`** here it is **`9001`**.